# Colon Parameters in C#, What does the colon stands for

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

In some functions while passing data i had seen syntax like this

```
obj = new demo("http://www.ajsldf.com", useDefault: true);
```

What is the meaning of **:** here and how it is different from other parameters which we pass in the methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are [Named Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd264739.aspx). They allow you to provide some context to the function argument you are passing in.

They must be last .. after all non-named arguments when calling a function. If there is more than one, they can be passed in any order.. as long as they come after any non-named ones.

E.g: this is wrong:

```
MyFunction(useDefault: true, other, args, here)
```

This is fine:

```
MyFunction(other, args, here, useDefault: true)
```

Where `MyFunction` might be defined as:

```
void MyFunction(string other1, string other2, string other3, bool useDefault)
```

This means, you can also do this:

```
MyFunction(
    other1: "Arg 1",
    other2: "Arg 2",
    other3: "Arg 3",
    useDefault: true
)
```

This can be really nice when you need to provide some context in an otherwise hard to comprehend function call. Take MVC routing for example, its hard to tell what's happening here:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

If you look at the definition .. it makes sense:

```
public static Route MapRoute(
    this RouteCollection routes,
    string name,
    string url,
    Object defaults
)
```

Whereas, with named arguments, its much easier to comprehend without looking at the documentation:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Also, if there are more than one named arguments, we can pass them in any order

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN reference i got it what i want to know that Named arguments free you from the need to remember or to look up the order of parameters in the parameter lists of called methods, I can call my parameter in any order is the main benefit. Will accept your answer as the time limit finishes